# R: Joining Tibbles Using Derived Column Values

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tibble, derivative

Consider the following tibbles:

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl_base_ids = tibble(base_id = c("ABC", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFGHI"), base_id_length = c(3, 6, 9), record_id_length = c(10, 12, 15))
tbl_records  = tibble(record_id = c("ABC1234567", "ABCDEF123456", "ABCDEFGHI123456"))
```

I'd like to join matching rows to produce a third tibble:

```
tbl_records_with_base 

  record_id
  base_id
  base_id_length
  record_id_length
```

As you can see, this is not a matter of joining one or more variables from each of the first two. This requires matching variable derivatives. In SQL, I'd do this:

```
  SELECT A.record_id, 
    B.base_id, 
    B.base_id_length, 
    B.record_id_length
  FROM tbl_records A 
    JOIN tbl_base_ids B 
      ON LENGTH(a.record_id) = B.record_id_length
        AND LEFT(a.record_id, B.base_id_length) = B.base_id
```

I've tried variations of dplyr joins and using the match function, to but to no avail. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should come up with some logic to separate `base_id` from `record_id`. because joining only on `record_id_length` would not be enough. For this example we can get `base_id` if we remove all numbers from `record_id`. Based on your actual dataset you need to change this if needed.

Once we do that we can join `tbl_records` with `tbl_base_ids` by `base_id` and `record_id_length`.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl_records %>%
  mutate(base_id = sub('\\d+', '', record_id),
         record_id_length = nchar(record_id)) %>%
  inner_join(tbl_base_ids, by = c("base_id", "record_id_length")) -> result

result

#  record_id       base_id   record_id_length base_id_length
#  <chr>           <chr>                <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 ABC1234567      ABC                     10              3
#2 ABCDEF123456    ABCDEF                  12              6
#3 ABCDEFGHI123456 ABCDEFGHI               15              9
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `fuzzyjoin` package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

tbl_base_ids %>%
  mutate(record_ptn = sprintf("^%s.{%i}$", base_id, pmax(0, record_id_length - base_id_length))) %>%
  regex_full_join(tbl_records, ., by = c("record_id" = "record_ptn"))
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   record_id       base_id   base_id_length record_id_length record_ptn     
#   <chr>           <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>          
# 1 ABC1234567      ABC                    3               10 ^ABC.{7}$      
# 2 ABCDEF123456    ABCDEF                 6               12 ^ABCDEF.{6}$   
# 3 ABCDEFGHI123456 ABCDEFGHI              9               15 ^ABCDEFGHI.{6}$
```

A note about this: the order of tables *matters*, where the regex must reside on the RHS of the `by=` settings. For instance, this does not work if we reverse it:

```r
tbl_base_ids %>%
  mutate(record_ptn = sprintf("^%s.{%i}$", base_id, pmax(0, record_id_length - base_id_length))) %>%
  regex_full_join(., tbl_records, by = c("record_ptn" = "record_id"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   base_id   base_id_length record_id_length record_ptn      record_id      
#   <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>           <chr>          
# 1 ABC                    3               10 ^ABC.{7}$       <NA>           
# 2 ABCDEF                 6               12 ^ABCDEF.{6}$    <NA>           
# 3 ABCDEFGHI              9               15 ^ABCDEFGHI.{6}$ <NA>           
# 4 <NA>                  NA               NA <NA>            ABC1234567     
# 5 <NA>                  NA               NA <NA>            ABCDEF123456   
# 6 <NA>                  NA               NA <NA>            ABCDEFGHI123456
```

Comment: Took me a minute, but I see you're creating a dynamic regular expression that will match each record_id. Very creative. Nice work.